# Passing undetermined number of arguments in R to the order() function

Tags: r, sorting

I've gathered that the order function in R can be used to sort rows of a data frame/matrix by one or more columns of that object. The columns are passed as separate arguments to order, and order can handle a variable number of arguments.

I would like to sort a data frame by all its columns, but I don't know the names or the number of columns in the data frame beforehand. In Python, one can unpack a list of objects as the arguments to a function (e.g. `zip(*mylist)` is `zip(mylist[0], mylist[1], etc...)`). Is there a similar way to do so in R? It would be nice to "unpack" the columns of a matrix when I call order.

Is there another way in R to sort by multiple columns besides passing an arbitrary number of parameters?

more thoughts:
It seems like I cannot just package multiple unnamed items into a single object to pass to order. Nor can I think of a way to use a for loop, apply, or do.call to make arbitrary numbers of objects. There's something here: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/custom-sort-td888802.html.

Or... should I write a for loop to call order on each column, starting with the least priority one and ending with the column that would've been the first argument to order, reordering the rows each time and making sure that order sorts stably?

Thanks.

Comment: Check out `example(order)`.  There are lots of useful examples

Comment: In R, `zip(*mylist)` would be `do.call("zip", mylist)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in python calling `fun(*args,**kwargs)` specifies the list of positional arguments (`*args`) and arguments to be matched by name (`kwargs`).

A similar call in R is `do.call(fun,arglist)`.  Unlike python, you cant mix regular and special arguments (e.g.  `fun(a=1,*args)`) and the second argument to `do.call` is can have elements that are matched by name or position (e.g. `do.call(fun,list(2,x=3))`)

To complete the example, since data.frames inherit from lists, you can simply call 'order(df)' to order on all the columns sequentially (as long as none of the names of the fields in your data.frame match the formal arguments of order 'na.last' and  'decreasing')

Comment: I didn't quite understand the use of do.call when I was writing my question, so thanks. In example(order), there is this idiom which solves my problem:
df[ do.call(order, df), ]